# Write a Python program which takes two list as input and returns True if they have at least 3 common elements

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am not able to covert list to set and also how to compare 3 elemnts in list

```
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    if len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 3:
        return True
    return False
a = [10,20,'Python', 10.20, 10+20j, [10,20,30], (10,20,30)]
b = [(10,20,30),1,20+3j,100.2, 10+20j, [10,20,30],'Python']
print(common_ele(a, b))
```

Comment: Why are you not able to convert list to set? `set()` converts a list to a set.

Comment: Your list contains another list, which is a mutable data type. That's the problem (and gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`). Items of a set must be immutable.

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: The problem statement is like this 
#Write a Python program which takes two list as input and returns True if they have at least 3 common elements.
#inp_lst1 = [10,20,'Python', 10.20, 10+20j, [10,20,30], (10,20,30)]
#inp_lst2 = [(10,20,30),1,20+3j,100.2, 10+20j, [10,20,30],'Python']

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important stuff. Also, please explain which kind of help you need. If anything is not working with the code you use, explain **what** does not work and how you tried to fix the non-working code

Answer (score 1):

You could define a helper function for converting the lists into sets:

```
import collections
from typing import Union


def make_into_set(xs: list[Union[int, str, float, complex, list[int], tuple[int, ...]]]) \
       -> set[Union[int, str, float, complex, tuple[int, ...]]]:
    return {x if isinstance(x, collections.abc.Hashable) else str(x) for x in xs}


def common_ele(a: list[Union[int, str, float, complex, list[int], tuple[int, ...]]],
               b: list[Union[int, str, float, complex, list[int], tuple[int, ...]]]) -> bool:
    a_set = make_into_set(a)
    b_set = make_into_set(b)
    return len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 3


a = [10, 20, 'Python', 10.20, 10+20j, [10, 20, 30], (10, 20, 30)]
b = [(10, 20, 30), 1, 20+3j, 100.2, 10+20j, [10, 20, 30], 'Python']
print(common_ele(a, b))
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

Comment: i am getting error for above code

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-8a4969d7dd4e> in <module>
      5 
      6 
----> 7 def make_into_set(xs: list[Union[int, str, float, complex, list[int], tuple[int, ...]]]) \
      8            -> list[Union[int, str, float, complex, tuple[int, ...]]]:
      9         return {x if isinstance(x, collections.abc.Hashable) else str(x) for x in xs}

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: It’s because you are not using Python 3.10 import List, Tuple from Typing or upgrade your Python version

Answer (score 1):

```py
def commonElement(a: list, b: list):
    common = 0
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            common += 1
    if common > 3:
        return True

a = [10,20,'Python', 10.20, 10+20j, [10,20,30], (10,20,30)]
b = [(10,20,30),1,20+3j,100.2, 10+20j, [10,20,30],'Python']
print(commonElement(a, b))
```

```py
True
```

The common elements are:

```py
Python
(10+20j)
[10, 20, 30]
(10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: Yes, a good O(n²) solution.

Comment: thank you the program working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

firstly for the each element of the list1 we will check if any of the list2 elements are same with it if it is same we will increase the number of the same elements **same += 1** after checking all of the elements we need to check same is bigger than 3

```
def check(list1, list2):
    same = 0  # number of the same elemetns
    for element1 in list1:
        for element2 in list2:
            if element1 == element2:  # check all of the elements
                same += 1
    return same >= 3
```

The return code (last line) is same as this:

```
if same >= 3:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Or you can use like this:
firstly for the all of the list1 elements check if it is in the list 2
if they are in the list2 it will append 1 to the list else 2 to the list
after that we will count how many 1's there are and if there are 3 or more 1's return True else return False

```
def checkSame(list1, list2):
    same = [(1 if i in list2 else 0) for i in list1].count(1)
    return same >= 3
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it